# Azure Stream Analytics - TopOne with Order by using input.EventEnqueuedUtcTime vs EventEnqueuedUtcTime

Tags: azure, stream, analytics

Today I was trying to fetch the recent record based on Event enqueued time. Initially, I tried below query which **didn't fetch** my recent record by time.

```
SELECT 
    TopOne() OVER (ORDER BY (CAST(eventHubInput.EventEnqueuedUtcTime AS DATETIME)) DESC) as FirstRecord 
FROM 
    eventHubInput 
WHERE 
    eventHubInput.SensorType = 'My Condition' 
GROUP BY 
    TumblingWindow(minute, 2)
```

Later instead of using eventHubInput.EventEnqueuedUtcTime I tried below query, Which **fetched** my **recent record**.

```
SELECT 
    TopOne() OVER (ORDER BY (CAST(EventEnqueuedUtcTime AS DATETIME)) DESC) as FirstRecord 
FROM 
    eventHubInput 
WHERE 
    eventHubInput.SensorType = 'My Condition' 
GROUP BY 
    TumblingWindow(minute, 2)
```

Note, second query is not using **eventHubInput.EventEnqueuedUtcTime**, instead I have replaced it with **EventEnqueuedUtcTime**.

I was not sure why the first query didn't fetch my recent events, can some point me what is the actual difference?

Thanks in advance.